# Flow of BasicAuthentication in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

My Django REST API has this class for authentication:

```
class AuthView(APIView):
      authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)

      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          login(request, request.user)
          data = {'testkey':'testvalue'}
          return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

When the credentials are correct, control is going to post method (which is fine).
However, for incorrect credentials, can someone please explain why the control is not going inside post method ?

I want to set a custom HTTP STATUS CODE for unauthenticated requests,(can't do that inside post, since control is not going there for unauthenticated requests) and am looking for a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I extended BasicAuthentication and overriden authenticate_credentials method like this:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class CustomAuth(BasicAuthentication):

    def authenticate_credentials(self, userid, password):
        """
        Override authenticate_credentials(..) of BasicAuthentication
        """
        user = authenticate(username=userid, password=password)
        '''if user is None or not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid username/password')'''
        return (user, None)
```

which seems to be working fine for now.
However, I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do this !!

Answer (score 1):

Control never enters your POST method because the Django Rest Framework (which you are using here) will first authenticate incoming requests using the `authentication_classes` that you specified, before entering the `post` method (or `get`, etc. — depending on the request).

The `BasicAuthentication` class that you are using here [throws an exception when credentials are incorrect](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/2.4.3/rest_framework/authentication.py#L56-L98) (that is the way Django Rest Framework works, as [documented here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4ce4a7c41a3e7b22dfb0aaeeea1c195e7db32447/docs/api-guide/authentication.md#custom-authentication)).

This stops the execution flow (so that it never reaches your method), and returns early with an error code.

---

Now, the actual code that implements this is in [`APIView.dispatch`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/2.4.3/rest_framework/views.py#L379-L406), which is called when a request is made. The `self.initial()` call is the one that ultimately calls the authentication code, whereas the one that calls your `post` method is the `handler(...)` line (which happens later, as you'll see).

---

To answer the second part of your question, Django Rest Framework is pretty opinionated about how things should be done, but you might be able to customize the status code by defining your own authentication class, but I doubt it.

Comment: I extended BasicAuthentication to override  authenticate_credentials method (Plz see my answer below), which seems to be working fine.
However, is this the right way to do it OR can there be any side effects ??

Answer (score -1):

Basic authentication is usually implemented by the browser.  I expect they only submit the post if the authentication passes.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1

Comment: The logic here is all happening within the Django Rest Framework that is processing the request, that `post` method is only called if authentication passes (fortunately — otherwise it'd be pretty easy to ignore authentication).